# how to display objects in a list view

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, listadapter

I am trying to populate a list view with a select all query from a data base (1 Primary Key, and 4 attributes. what I have now is not throwing errors, but its not generating anything that is usable. Below is the query that I am using:

```
public List<SavedLocation> getAllLocationDescriptions() {
        List<SavedLocation> locationList = new ArrayList<SavedLocation>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOCATIONS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                SavedLocation location = new SavedLocation();


                location.setLocation(cursor.getString(0));



                // Adding locationt to list
                locationList.add(location);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return locationList;
    }
```

This is my list view activity. (note: the log output is writing the correct results, so that seems to be working)

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class SavedLocationsListTest extends ListActivity{



    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        List<SavedLocation> test = db.getAllLocationDescriptions();



        for (SavedLocation cn : test){
            String log = "ID: "+ cn.getID()+ ", Location:" + cn.getLocation() + ", Accuracy:"+ cn._accuracy+ ", Description: " +cn._description+ ", Provider:" + cn.getProvider();
            Log.d("Location: ", log);}


        setListAdapter (new ArrayAdapter<SavedLocation>(this, R.layout.list_test,test));
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    }



}
```

and this is my xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textView0"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        </TextView>
```

and now as I said, I'm not getting errors, but I feel like what I am getting is even more frustrating; I have 4 records in my database and this is what I keep getting as the output when running the app:

- com.example.gpstest1.SavedLocation@41eb8128 
  com.example.gpstest1.SavedLocation@41eb8218 
  com.example.gpstest1.SavedLocation@41eb8270
  com.example.gpstest1.SavedLocation@41eb82c8

it looks like I'm able to populate the list view, I'm just doing it wrong.

Comment: cursor.getString(0) what does this return id or location? and also your only setting location when `getAllLocationDescriptions()`

Comment: my rational behind only setting the location was that I only wanted to display the location. I orignaly had it set up to set everything, but in my frustration I started trying everything in the hopes I could at least get it to 'half work'. based off of the answer below though, it would seem thats not the root cause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your TextViews are displaying information like `com.example.gpstest1.SavedLocation@41eb8128` is that you haven't overriden the `toString()` method in your `SavedLocation` class.

The ArrayAdapter class has no idea how to convert your Java objects into a readable format. It can't read your mind and determine what a valid textual representation of a `SavedLocation` might be. The best it can do is call `toString()` on your object and hope for the best.

According to the [`Object.toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) documentation, the default implementation of `toString()` does this:

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of
>   the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
>   character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
>   code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal
>   to the value of: getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())

You have a few options. The easiest is to just override `toString()` in your `SavedLocation` and have it output what you want. This will work well if you really just want a single TextView to represent each entry.

If you want a more complicated layout, you will want to create your own ArrayAdapter subclass that overrides `getView()` to generate the appropriate View for each row in the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

well I ended up changing:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        List<SavedLocation> test = db.getAllLocationDescriptions();



        for (SavedLocation cn : test){
            String log = "ID: "+ cn.getID()+ ", Location:" + cn.getLocation() + ", Accuracy:"+ cn._accuracy+ ", Description: " +cn._description+ ", Provider:" + cn.getProvider();

            Log.d("Location: ", log);}


        setListAdapter (new ArrayAdapter<SavedLocation>(this, R.layout.list_test,test));
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

to:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_main);



        Intent intent = getIntent();

        displayList();

    }

    public void displayList(){

        Cursor cursor=db.getAllLocationsCursor();

        String from [] = new String[] {db.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, db.COLUMN_LOCATION, db.KEY_ID};
        int to [] = new int[]{R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3 };



        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_item, cursor, from, to, 0);


        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
```

If I have the terminology correct, I'm using a "cursor adapter" to accomplish this...?